# How to hide menubar, ftoolbar in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a HTML page. I would like to hide the menubar, ftoolbar in IE when the page id opened.

I do not want to open the page from another web page (`window.open(....)`). I just want to open the current web page directly!

How can I do this with jQuery or plain JavaScript?

Comment: You can't in the current window. Not speaking of how bad this actually is for the experience. You can only open new windows without these features and then close the your `window.opener`. http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/window.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx#properties
There is no properties dealing with browser menu bars.

I believe the main reason - is the security risk they create. Imagine how mad user would become if he couldn't click "Back" or type new web adress after your page loads? And what if your page hacked to become a browsers homepage? This would result in browser being bugged.